# ASP.Net core, How to log users information when a check box is checked?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, logging

I have been struggling to find information on how to log users information such as there username when a checkbox gets selected (This information should be logged without the user knowing). Here is my code:

This is a 'switch' designed checkbox from MDB

```
<div>
<div class="switch">
    <label>
        Checked and Verified
        <input type="checkbox" checked>
        <span class="lever"></span>

    </label>
</div>
```

When the 'leaver' (checkbox) is made to true I would like this to be logged:

```
<input id="username" value="@User.Identity.Name" />

@Html.EditorFor(x => x.DateCreated)
```

However, I cannot find a @if statement or any javascript code that works. 
Please help me :(

Comment: when you say "logged", what do really mean to happen? append a line to a text file on the server? anyway inserting the user name from a server tag into the client markup and then posting it back is unsafe - users can overwrite that with anything.

Comment: I am making a document log. What I am currently trying to do is when a user uploads a file I want to save the 'PersonId' (This is the user's unique id) and the current DateTime, all of this should be hidden without the user sees and it is all going to be stored in a table within the database. @dlatikay

Comment: ok. you should not do this on client side at all. users could modify this information in their client browser and submit data that has been tampered with. user name should be known by prior authentication and read from server-side session storage only. The same goes for the current date, you could even use the database backend's `GETDATE` or `systime` etc. for the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JavaScript:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()" checked>
```

You can build your logic in JS:

```
function myFunction() {
  // Get the checkbox
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");


  // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    //log
  } else {
    //do not log
  }
}
```

Like described here [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_display_checkbox_text.asp)

Comment: Thank-you for your quick response, this is helpful thank-you, however, do you know where to look for some javascript code to log a users name and the current time? also, how will I pass this information into the model?

Comment: Are you calling an API? or just a MVC controller? Need more info to help you.

Comment: MVC Controller & I am sorry my questions vague,b ask as many questions as you please.

Comment: Okay. If the user is logged in and assuming you are using IdentityModel, you can get the username from the User object in the back-end or front-end. You can get the current date using the system. In the backend (c#): var currentTime = DateTime.Now and for JS: var currentTime = new Date(); Here is a link that explains how to pass data in your MVC Controller with JQuery and Ajax https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1078491/Creating-Forms-in-ASP-NET-MVC and a video link https://app.pluralsight.com/player?author=scott-allen&name=mvc4-building-m6-ajax&mode=live&clip=0&course=mvc4-building